# How to realize sending otp on the phone?

Tags: python, django, twilio, one-time-password

I am trying to implement phone registration using twilio, python and django

I can`t comprehend how i have to realize mechanism , that takes input from user for texting him

**Generating otp and sending to user:**

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import random
otp=random.randint(1000,9999)


account_sid = ''
auth_token = ''

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

client.messages.create(from_='+',
                      to='+',
                      body='Your OTP is -'+str(otp))
```

When user inputs his phone number, it sends to the server

But how i can place his number at `to =" _HERE_ "` , when he sends it to the server and how i can call this file then?

Comment: Are you asking how you can take a user input from, preferably a form, and put this inside the `to` positional argument?

Comment: @Sahli, that`s right

Comment: Where does the user input come from? Are you using another python app for getting some user input?

Comment: @devnull, user inputs his number into **html-form** and then clicks "submit"

Comment: *how i can call this file then* wrap it in a function and call the function you may need a model to verfiy what otp you have sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views simply get the user input and send it to the `positional argument`.

views.py

```
from django.views import View


class SendOTP(View):
    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            to = request.POST.get('to')
            _from = request.POST.get('from')
            client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
            client.messages.create(from_=_from,
                                  to=to,
                                  body='Your OTP is -'+str(otp))
```

template.html

```
<form method="post">
{%csrf_token%}
    <input type="text" name="to">
    <input type="text" name="from">
</form>
```

Comment: Manually checking if request is `post` isn't required if you're using class based views but in case someone sees this with function based views, this will be helpful.

Comment: w8, but how `SendOTP` will understand that it has to take exactly this request `to`?

Comment: May be there are need kinda like `<form action = "url "` ?

Comment: Why do u think that file will get it with no problem ?

Comment: `form action="{% url url-name %}"`. This should work.

Comment: I don't understand this comment, can you please clarify. "w8, but how `SendOTP` will understand that it has to take exactly this request `to`?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201138/discussion-between-mickeyul-and-sahil).